# Modelling parents and children in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to model a Parent and a number of Children in Rails 4.  The relationships I'm trying to model is that each child will have two Parents and each Parent can have many children.  I've been able to model a single parent and many child relationship like so:

```
rails g model Parent name:string
rake db:migrate
rails g model Child name:string parent_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

I can then create a parent like so:

```
rails console
Parent.create(name: 'Joe Bloggs')
```

Which gives me a parent with id 1.  I can join this to a new child like so:

```
Child.create(name: 'Jane Bloggs', parent_id: 1)
```

Then I add in the relationship to the model class `child.rb`:

```
belongs_to :parent
```

So I can now run:

```
Child.first.parent
```

How can I extend this so that the Child can have a mother parent and a father parent?

Comment: could you please show some code, what you tried before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an attempt to answer my own question, I managed to get this to work.  It relied on changing my Child model so that it has a `mother_id:integer` and a `father_id:integer`.  I then added the following to `child.rb`:

```
has_one :mother, :class_name => "Parent", :primary_key => "mother_id", :foreign_key => "id"
has_one :father, :class_name => "Parent", :primary_key => "father_id", :foreign_key => "id"
```

And this then enabled me to link a single Child with two parents and support the following:

```
Child.first.father
Child.first.mother
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use has_and_belongs_to_many association here! Please read documentation [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)